# Apple ID creation for Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I want to ask if anyone knows if it's true. I always thought that from Apple device you can create only 3 Apple ID. But on the group AppleDevAccouts discussion on Telegram they've said that you can do 3 normal and 2 if you turn on Two-Step Verification before. I was searching to solve the problem with Apple Developer Account creation.

Does anybody now? It is true about 5 acc from one device? Has anyone tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but about 3rd party terms of service restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this.
First, I activated 3 accounts on the device.
Then I created 2 more accounts - set 2 step-verification on Appleid.com - login to the account on the device - turn off 2 step-verification on Appleid.com - set 2-factor authentication on the device.
5 activated accounts with 1 device in total.